# Why TypeORM requires the second parameter, inverseSide property (even though it's optional)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm learning Typescript and TypeORM with NestJS at the same time. Recently, I came across a use-case using the OneToMany and ManyToOne relation decorator. Ahead of time, I notice that having OneToMany and ManyToOne relations together, developers often put the OneToMany property as the second parameter of ManyToOne for instance

```
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.photos)
```

I wonder why `user.photos` is necessary there, I tried without the `user.photos` and it seems to be working fine, I'm being anxious about this property, can anyone help me clarify on this matter? Thank you very much.

To give some more context, here's a referral link that I'm not very clear of. Appreciate all of your guidance:-
[Why does TypeORM require the inverse side of OneToMany to be provided, but doesn't require the inverse side of ManyToOne to be provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944885/why-does-typeorm-require-the-inverse-side-of-onetomany-to-be-provided-but-doesn)

Answer (score 3):

**tldr**

It is used during metamodel construction, validation, some error messages and by the `QueryBuilder` API.

The reason TypeORM seems to be working fine without it is that you probably missed the specific use cases where it would fail.

---

If you inspect the source of one of the mapping decorators, for example `OneToOne`, you will see how the value is used:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/relations/OneToOne.ts#L53

```
export function OneToOne<T>(typeFunctionOrTarget: string|((type?: any) => ObjectType<T>),
                        inverseSideOrOptions?: string|((object: T) => any)|RelationOptions,
                        options?: RelationOptions): PropertyDecorator {

// ...

return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    // ...

    getMetadataArgsStorage().relations.push({
        // ...
        inverseSideProperty: inverseSideProperty,
        // ...
    } as RelationMetadataArgs);
```

Searching the repo and following along the usage of the properties you will see, that it is ultimately used to produce an `inverseRelation` property on a metamodel object which is later used for further metamodell construction, error reporting, metamodel validation and in the `QueryBuilder`.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f27622daf9784d06496975bbbcacdb0938fd2c82/src/metadata/RelationMetadata.ts#L281

```
export class RelationMetadata {

// ...

constructor(options: {
    entityMetadata: EntityMetadata,
    embeddedMetadata?: EmbeddedMetadata,
    args: RelationMetadataArgs
}) {
    
    // ...

    if (args.inverseSideProperty)
        this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory = args.inverseSideProperty;

    // ...
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f27622daf9784d06496975bbbcacdb0938fd2c82/src/metadata/RelationMetadata.ts#L521

```
buildInverseSidePropertyPath(): string {

    if (this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory) {
        const ownerEntityPropertiesMap = this.inverseEntityMetadata.propertiesMap;
        if (typeof this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory === "function")
            return this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory(ownerEntityPropertiesMap);

        if (typeof this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory === "string")
            return this.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory;

    }

    // ...

    return "";
}
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f27622daf9784d06496975bbbcacdb0938fd2c82/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts#L667

```
protected computeInverseProperties(entityMetadata: EntityMetadata, entityMetadatas: EntityMetadata[]) {
    entityMetadata.relations.forEach(relation => {

        // ...

        relation.inverseEntityMetadata = inverseEntityMetadata;
        relation.inverseSidePropertyPath = relation.buildInverseSidePropertyPath();

        // and compute inverse relation and mark if it has such
        relation.inverseRelation = inverseEntityMetadata.relations.find(foundRelation => foundRelation.propertyPath === relation.inverseSidePropertyPath);
    });
```

At this point, you can search for the uses of `.inverseRelation` and you will have a good starting point for answering your question.

Note, that there are a couple of disabled validations (inside comments) using the aforementioned property: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f27622daf9784d06496975bbbcacdb0938fd2c82/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.ts#L133-L187

---